# Report Builder 3 - Parameter Pane Customization

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Currently, I'm looking to use the Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder on a few web applications to run reports. But I wanted to change the styling of the parameter pane to make it look cohesive with the application instead of looking like it was placed last minute.

I've looked through the following documentation with no luck:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220464(v=sql.110).aspx

Does anyone know if it is possible to style the parameter pane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the styling using CSS.

This link might help you: http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s296/css-parameters.htm

Comment: This definitely helped a lot! Thank you so much. Also another link I found to go with this which helps get to the initial CSS - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345247(v=sql.110).aspx